# How sort an array of tags when it is updated?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, meteor

Can't find how to sort an array when it is updated. What is wrong? Thanks!

***this not working:***

```
Template.doc.events({
    'submit form': function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newTag =  event.target.tags.value;

        if (!!newTag) { // if not empty
            MyPix.update(this._id, {
                $addToSet: {
                    'metadata.tags': {
                            $each: [ newTag ],
                    }
                },
                $sort: {
                    'metadata.tags':  1
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Error: *update failed: Access denied. Operator $sort not allowed in a restricted collection.*

***this not working either:***

```
Template.doc.events({
    'submit form': function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newTag =  event.target.tags.value;

        if (!!newTag) { // if not empty
            MyPix.update(this._id, {
                $addToSet: {
                    'metadata.tags': {
                            $each: [ newTag ],
                    }
                },
                $push: {
                    'metadata.tags': { 
                        $each: [ ], $sort: -1
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Error: *update failed: MongoError: Field name duplication not allowed with* modifiers

Comment: Why do you want sort array on update? You sort it when you push it to client, in DB it isnt sorted

Comment: Is that so? I had thought about sorting on the client but was not sure why not do it right away. @Sindis

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB 2.6 you can use the `$position` modifier to specify the location in an array at which `$push` inserts values.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position

The current version of Meteor (1.0.3.1) doesn't support 2.6, but we will add support soon.  Using `$position` on the client (more precisely, in [minimongo](https://www.meteor.com/mini-databases)) will require adding support for `$position` to minimongo.  We'd welcome a pull request.